# Get header details based on the colour of a cell in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet which has 4 columns (A:D). The 1st row contains the header and second row onwards, there are different values but 1 of the 4 cell in the row is coloured in yellw. Based on which cell is coloured in yellow, I have to get the header value in column E.

[image]

I tried using the below formulas:
**=INDEX($A1:$D1, 1, MATCH(TRUE, INDEX(COLUMN($A2:$D2)*(CELL("color", $A2:$D2) = 6), 0), 0))**

To confirm the colour code I tried using the formula **=IF(CELL("COLOR",E2)=6,"YES","NO")**. This also returned the value **NO**.

Comment: A formula will never be able to "read" the background color of a cell. Do you know the logic, why a cell is colored? If not - you wil have to write VBA code to retrieve what you want.

Comment: Did you check the [`CELL`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf) documentation on what the `"color"` argument actually refers to? It's not what you think.

Comment: There is no logic for the colour. The sheets contains 4 answer options of which the highlighted cell is the correct answer.

Comment: Then you need VBA

Comment: Got the solution. As per your replies, I went through the VBA for color logic. All I had to do was create a function in VBA for Yellow colour and then use the same in my formula. Below is the function which allowed me to identify the colored cell.

Function COLOUR(Rge As Range) As Boolean
If Rge.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then COLOUR = True
End Function


Below is the formula I used to get the value of the header using the function created.

=IF(colour(A2),$A$1,IF(colour(B2),$B$1,IF(colour(C2),$C$1,IF(colour(D2),$D$1))))


Thank you.